# How do you use the value of a named cell in a macro in a different sheet, same workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I'm just not getting it, I'm using Excel 2003 and am totally confused as I'm just not getting it ...can anyone help?  I need to check that named value with a number of column headings on the active sheet and then insert a column to the left of the column holding the matching text.  I'm sure that bit is very hard - but I'm not even able to get started here...

Comment: Not sure your question is clear. Are you looking for a value in column headings which you have defined as a name in the workbook? Or do you have a named cell range with a value you are trying use in someway? It sounds as if the value you are looking for may be in multiple column headings, so it is not clear where you have defined the name.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to get your named value column (which I presume is a named range...), you would use:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("mySheet").Range("myRange").Column
```

So you could do something like:

```
myNamedRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("mySheet").Range("myNamedRange").Value
myCol = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("myMainSheet").Rows("1:1").Find(myNamedRange).Column
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("myMainSheet").Cells(1, myCol).EntireColumn.Insert
```